# How to prevent plane from clogging?

Tags: sharpening, plane

I've sharpened an old blade from a smoothing plane by hand, using sandpaper and no jig. It was very dull, so I'm not sure the angle was ok before. Now I'm getting these shavings that curl up too fast and clog the plane.

Could this be caused by a wrong angle when sharpening or is this probably caused by something else?

[image: Shaving from my plane]

Comment: Please see [hand plane controls (bevel down)](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/hand-plane-controls-bevel-down/5462#5462). Make some adjustments along the lines of the suggestions and your problem should go away.

Comment: *"Could this be caused by a wrong angle when sharpening "* If the plane can cut at all this isn't the issue. Only if you get the honing angle much too steep (approximately 45° or steeper) will you have a big problem as the cutting edge has no 'relief' which prevents the sharp edge from taking a shaving in the normal way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hand plane controls (bevel down)](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/hand-plane-controls-bevel-down)

Comment: For fine surfacing (i.e. smoothing) this is actually what you want.  It's not unusual when using a fine-set smoothing plane to have to pull out your shaving at the end of each pass.  Specifically, you're getting a "type 2" shaving.  If you need to remove material quickly back off your chipbreaker, open your mouth, and try for a "type 1" shaving.  More detail here: http://planetuning.infillplane.com/html/shaving_formation.html

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, there will always be times that shavings bunch in the throat but a setting that gets this effect shouldn't be something to aim for. Because this is easy-planing SPF and not something more difficult it should be possible to set your plane so that shavings sail out of the throat just as they tend to on a coffin smoother, q.v. The English Woodworker's demos.

Comment: This ribbon formation occurs when the chipbreaker is set very close to the blade edge. They are not necessarily a problem, but setting a close chipbreaker is only something you might want for final smoothing. If you're doing final smoothing with a finely set chipbreaker, you can open the mouth (either directly or by moving back the frog - depends on your plan) to reduce clogging.

Comment: @Graphus I think you're saying the same thing I was.  I would agree that there's no reason to use a fine-set smoother on SPF.  It's not going to get a surface any better than a jack or normally set smoother.  On a fine smoother you want it set up so it's hard to push and almost choking on the shavings from the breaker being so close to the edge.  But you only use one on figured wood, hard splintery wood, when you're forced to work against the grain, or other problem situations.